# How to select a next word in a string if string contains true using C#

Tags: c#, string

```
 1. Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Duration: 01:49:36.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1069 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 935 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 libx264
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
```

**In the above string i need only 01:49:36.75, how to get only the next word of "Duration:" in one line of code**

Comment: Make use of `.Substring()` with `.IndexOf()`

Comment: That entire code block is a string?

Comment: yes, its a complete string

Comment: if(mystring.contains("Duration"){  .......} is any possibility to select once the condition is true here

Comment: @un-lucky the indexof the word "01:49:36.75" is not constant may it change some times ..

Answer (score 1):

Assume s is your string, and these '*' do not exist (I guess you added it):

```
string sDurationVal = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("Duration") + 9).Split(',')[0].Trim();
```

- Use **Substring** and **IndexOf** to remove the first part of the string, such that the new string starts with the desired value.
- **Split** the result by ',' and take the first cell.
- **Trim** it to remove unnecessary spaces.

Comment: Sure. Notice that you must verify that the string "Duration" (case-sensitive) indeed exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Regex` class to find what you're looking for.
Regex use `Regular Expression Language`.

```
 Regex rx = new Regex(@"Duration\:\s*([\d\.]+)\,",RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 Console.WriteLine(rx.Matches("Your String")[0].Groups[0].Value);
```

For more information you can check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

The Regex is reliable than the other methods like split or IndexOf ...

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `.Substring()` along with `.IndexOf()`

```
string s2 = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("Duration:")+9,12).Trim();
```